# Return value from chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In popup.js i'm using the following code to display all the text within a certain div id of the current tab -  and display in alert. I'm wondering how would it be possible to save the div text to a variable within popup.js?

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,code:"alert(document.getElementById(\"DIVid\").innerText.split(' '))"});
```

The above works fine, but when i try this:

```
var getText = chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,code:"document.getElementById(\"DIVid\").innerText.split(' ')"});
```

or

```
var getText = chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,code:"document.getElementById(\"DIVid\").innerText.split(' ')"},function(response){return response});
```

Nothing is stored. I'm obviously going about this the wrong way. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17):

Use the following code,

```
var getText = Array();
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[tab].id, {
    "code": "document.getElementById(\"_Your_ID_Here_\").innerText.split(' ')"
}, function (result) {
    for (i = 0; i < result[0].length; i++)
    getText [i] = result[0][i];
    console.log(getText);
});
```

You have update variable inside callback, because of async nature of **chrome.api**

Answer (score 2):

Here's a modern and concise way to achieve that :

Defining a reusable promise-like wrapper function

```js
const executeScript = (tabId, func) => new Promise(resolve => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({ target: { tabId }, func }, resolve)
}
```

Usage :

```js
const [{result: selection}] = await executeScript(tabId,
  () => document.getSelection().toString()
)
console.log(selection) // log page selection
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [chrome.scripting.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#method-executeScript), I've noticed that `func` can't return an object directly. I had to serialize the response with `JSON.parse`, otherwise the script would never return the value.

**Broken:**

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: request.tabId },
    world: 'MAIN',
    func: () => {
      const sessionService = window.namespace.__container__.lookup('service:session');
      const user = sessionService.get('user');
      const course = sessionService.get('course');
      const activity = sessionService.get('activity');
      return { user, course, activity };
    }
  }, (bundleInfo) => {
    console.log(bundleInfo) // This never gets logged
  });
```

**Working:**

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: request.tabId },
    world: 'MAIN',
    func: () => {
      const sessionService = window.namespace.__container__.lookup('service:session');
      const user = sessionService.get('user');
      const course = sessionService.get('course');
      const activity = sessionService.get('activity');
      return JSON.stringify({ user, course, activity }); // Serialize the object before returning
    }
  }, (bundleInfo) => {
    console.log(bundleInfo);
  });
```