# About chrome.tabs.executeScript, returning multiple values

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This works perfectly in my Chrome Extension :

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( null, {code:"var x = 53; x"},
function(results){ alert(results[0]); } );
```

However, I want to return two variables, but I don't know how to do it ..

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( null, {code:"var x = 53; var y = 71; ??? x,y ???"},
function(results){ alert(results[0]); alert(results[1]); } );
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: may this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790389/return-value-from-chrome-tabs-executescript) helps.

Comment: I've already seen it but it didn't answer my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put values into an array or a Javascript object and return it. For example:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( null, {code:"var x = [53,71]; x "},
            function(results){ alert(results); } );
```

Comment: And I should use results[0][0] and results[0][1] to get the two values .. thanks ! :)

Comment: @Mayusu, Indeed, since this is the case why is the result even an array in the first place? Why not just an object?

Comment: @Pacerier
as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166293/about-chrome-tabs-executescript-id-details-callback), you can inject your code into all frames of current page. So, results contains all the execution results.