# How to get an element text from a newly created chrome tab using chrome.tabs.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs

Im very new in creating a chrome extension.

I have created few tabs using the code:

chrome.tabs.create({url:"https://www.example.com/user.html#e"+userId, active:true}, function(tab){}

Post creation how can I access the DOM and elements inside the newly created tabs.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Content scripts**

Chrome extensions can access the DOM via [content scripts.](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

As the docs explain, these scripts can be loaded into tabs and then access the DOM from there. For example:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "name": "Hello world",
  "description": "Sample extension using content script",
  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "tabs"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "contentScript.js"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

contentScript.js:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById("mySelect");

// Logic to alter myElement, etc.
```

If you want to send messages and data between the content script and the background of your extension then you'll need to take a look at [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

**chrome.tabs.executeScript**

You can also access the DOM using the [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) method.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14828551/4774345) explains how.

Comment: Thanks Dan for inputs. Can I have a JS file instead of "code" where I can have all the logic related for reading the elements in each tab I have created?

Comment: @Ram's sure, if you want a separate file that's injected into each tab then you want to use content scripts. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks again Dan. Now I can able set the background color using the 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";'. But there are few elements which are loading very slowly so that my query to get an element text is executes before the page loads so I'm getting an error. Your thoughts please

Comment: @Ram's You can run content scripts at "document_start", "document_end", or "document_idle" which is configured via "run_at" in manifest.json. Check the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for what each of these mean. You might want to use document_idle or include some logic in your content script to check for the element and once run once it exists.

Comment: @Ram's no problem!